# MySql Grouping with Most Recent Values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've got quite a long query that collects data from various sources to create a report on jobs being checked.

**Just to add a bit of context:**
*I have a table of 'jobs'. Each of these jobs is linked to a certain area and location and given a complexity rating depending on how difficult the job is. Each job is checked by a supervisor, scored out of 10 and then entered onto the system. Depending on the score it achieves it is given a complexity rating and an interval to be checked again. i.e. lower score means checked more often than higher score.*

I'm writing a query that collects each job by ID, name, etc, and then gets the last time it was checked, the next time it's due to be checked as well as the current score, who entered it onto the system and actual supervisor who checked the job.

**Unfortunately the query I have isn't giving me the most recent values but rather the least recent. Besides the "Last_Checked" field (see below). For this the MAX() function is working; however with other fields this isn't relevant.**

*Here's a breakdown of the tables and query:*

**Table 1 : Jobs**

```
Job_ID | Job_Name | Job_Area | Job_Location | Job_Complexity
1        MyJob      1          1              2
2        AnothJob   1          2              1
```

**Table 2 : Areas**

```
Area_ID | Area_Name
1         Area
```

**Table 3 : Locations**

```
Location_ID | Location_Area | Location_Name
1             1               MyLocation1
2             1               MyLocation2
```

**Table 4 : Complexity**

```
Complexity_ID | Complexity_Label | Complexity_Interval_Days
1               Very Difficult     25
2               Difficult          35
```

**Table 5 : Users**

```
User_ID | User_FirstName | User_LastName
1         Jane             Doe
```

**Table 6 : Supervisors**

```
Supervisor_ID | Supervisor_FirstName | Supervisor_LastName
1               John                   Doe
2               Barry                  Sheen
```

**Table 7 : Checks**

```
Check_ID | Check_Job_ID | Check_Date | Check_Score | Check_User | Check_Supervisor
1          1              27-03-17     8             1            1
2          1              28-03-17     5             1            2
3          1              29-03-17     6             1            2
```

**Current Query**

```
SELECT
j.Job_ID,
a.Area_Name,
d.Location_Name,
j.Job_Name,
MAX(c.Checked_Date) as Last_Checked,
Date_Add(MAX(c.Checked_Date), interval r.Complexity_TimePeriod day) as Due_Date,
Datediff(Date_Add(MAX(c.Checked_Date), interval r.Complexity_TimePeriod day), Now()) as Due_Days,
c.Check_Score as Current_Score,
CONCAT(u.User_FirstName, ' ', u.User_LastName) as Entered_By,
CONCAT(s.Supervisor_FirstName, ' ', s.Supervisor_LastName) as Supervisor,
r.Complexity_Level

from Jobs_active j

left join pdc_admin.admin_areas a
on a.Area_ID = j.Job_area

left join pdc_admin.admin_Locations l
on l.Location_ID = j.Job_Location

left join Jobs_Checks c
on c.Check_Job_ID = j.Job_ID

left join pdc_admin.admin_users u
on u.user_id = c.Check_Person

left join Jobs_Complexity_config r
on r.Complexity_ID = j.Job_Complexity

left join admin_Supervisors s on
s.Supervisor_ID = c.Check_Supervisor

group by j.Job_ID
```

What I'd like to get from this would be something like so:

```
Job_ID | Area_Name | Location_Name | Job_Name | Last_Checked | Due_Date | Due_Days | Current_Score | Entered_By | Supervisor | Complexity_Level
1        Area      | MyLocation1     MyJob      29-03-17       03-05-17   35         6               Jane Doe     Barry Sheen  Difficult
```

As you can see, the results show the latest fields (i.e. score/supervisor who checked) but don't show any more than 1 row per job. In essence, I am after the latest information about each job without showing anything about the previous times it has been checked.

Information overload... all help is appreciated thank-you!

Comment: Left justified SQL, so hard to read...

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid! Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), or return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.